# Time series $MA(2)$ projection $X_t$ onto $H_{t-1}$

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, moving-average

I have an $MA(2)$ process $X_t = Z_t - Z_{t-1} + 0.25Z_{t-2}$ where $Z_t \sim WN(0, \sigma^2)$ and I need to find a projection of $X_t$ onto space $H_{t-1}(X_t)$, but how to do that?

I guess my projection will be a linear combination $P_{H_{t-1}}X_t = \sum\limits_1^{\infty}a_iX_{t-i}$ but how to do it legitimately? Or maybe it is easier to find a projection onto $Z_t$ (as $X_t$ is both causal and invertible)?

Could anyone explain me what to do in these kind of problems (also when I am projecting onto, for instance, $sp(X_1,...X_t)$). Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I got $Z_t = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}0.5^i(i+1)X_{t-i}$. I know that my process is both causal and invertible, so basically a projection onto $H(X)$ is the same as onto $H(Z)$. So is my projection just $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}0.5^i(i+1)X_{t-i}$? Please notice that I changed $i$ from $0$ to $1$ as I am cutting off $X_t$ as it is not included in a subspace I'm projecting onto.

Comment: Hi: that's not an AR(2) as written. It could be viewed as an MA(2) if you add $Z_t$ and $Z_{t-1}$ and call it $Z^{*}_t$.

Comment: With regard to my comment above, note that $Z^{*}_{t}$ will be a normal RV with twice the variance as the other MA term.

Comment: @mlofton you are absolutely correct, it was a typo, that's $MA(2)$

Comment: No problem. Usually MA models are estimated using a likellhood approach with a constraint to ensure uniqueness. I'm not familar with projection approaches unless maximizing the likelihood can be thought of as a projection. Hopefully someone else can be more helpful.

Comment: @mlofton could you please take a look at solution that I've added?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Amal: I'm just putting this into answer for room but it's not really an answer.

We have: $X_t = \epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1} + 0.25 \epsilon_{t-2}$.
( I changed $Z_{t}$ to $\epsilon_t$ since I'm more used to that noation).

So, using the lag operator gives:

$X_t = (1 - L + 0.25 L^2) \epsilon_t$

But I'm not clear on how you went from there to what you obtained ?

I'm not sure that it can be considered a projection, but the MLE for the MA
is generally obtained in the following way:

We know that each $X_t$ is normally distributed with mean $E(\epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t-2}) = 0$ and variance (2 + $\frac{1}{16})\sigma^2$.

So, the first step is to initialize by setting  the  estimates of $\epsilon_{0}$ and $\epsilon_{1}$ to $0$ since they are not directly obtainable.

Then, from the model,  $\hat{\epsilon_{2}} = X_{2} + \hat{\epsilon_{1}} - 0.25 \hat{\epsilon}_{0}$

$\hat{\epsilon_{3}} = X_{3} + \hat{\epsilon_{2}} - 0.25 \hat{\epsilon}_{1}$

$\hat{\epsilon_{4}} = X_{4} + \hat{\epsilon_{3}} - 0.25 \hat{\epsilon}_{2}$

and so on and so forth until the $\epsilon_t$ are obtained $\forall ~ t$.

And you keep obtaining them recursively in that manner. Then, once you
have them, you minimize the sum of their squares because this is equivalent to maximizing the density of the likelihood since its normal.  This approach possibly can be viewed as a projection but I'm not sure. Also, their are better methods for initializion of the first two $\hat{\epsilon}$. The intitialization issue is mostly likely discussed in Box-Jenkins and Reinsel. Also, note that your projection approach might be equivalent. I just don't follow how you obtained it.